# Normalizing space characters in Prolog atoms

Tags: string, prolog, whitespace

What is the best way to normalize whitespace characters (space, newline, tab) in a Prolog atom, e.g. in SWI-Prolog.
I.e. I would like to have a rule:

```
normalize_space_in_atom(+Atom1, -Atom2)
```

such that `Atom2`

- has any sequence of whitespace characters turned into a single space
- starts with a non-space
- ends with a non-space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SWI Prolog provides normalize_space/2, and so you could define your predicate as follows:

```
normalize_space_in_atom(A1,A2) :- normalize_space(atom(A2),A1).
```

I've tried this out with SWI Prolog 5.7.5 and it appears to work. You could add more error handling if you wish.

Comment: Thanks, works in 5.6.61 as well. I can't believe I couldn't find it in the documentation.